# C++ concept with std::is_convertible_to (missing doc?)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am reading the docs for C++ concepts ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints ) and stumbled upon this very first example:

```
template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a)
{
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
```

The full example compiles with built-in gcc C++20 and the docs say:

```
the expression std::hash<T>{}(a) compiles and
its result is convertible to std::size_t
```

I checked the signature of std::is_convertable_to and it has two parameters (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to):

```
template <class From, class To>
```

How can a concept-"template" have two parameters when only one argument is passed to it?
Is this omission on the docs side or is it some kind of C++20 concept-magic?

UPD: constraints inside concept specification assume one implicit argument (the passed type).

Comment: This a case where you'd have gotten your answer by just continuing to read the very first wiki page you linked: *"In a type-constraint, a concept takes one less template argument than its parameter list demands, because the contextually deduced type is implicitly used as the first argument of the concept."*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I am now wondering if "->" is some kind of "&&" that can be stacked further or it is only allowed to be in this two operands form.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires

Answer (score 1):

When you type

```
template<std::convertible_to<std::size_t> X>
void foo(X x);
```

you only pass one of the template parameters explicitly.

What happens is that the compiler converts this to (roughly)

```
template<class X>
requires std::convertible_to<X, std::size_t>
void foo(X x);
```

prepending the template argument lists with the type `X` and checking the concept.

The same works with:

```
void foo(std::convertible_to<std::size_t> auto x);
```

where the type of `x` is tested by prepending it to `std::convertible_to<std::size_t>` list, and the same with

```
template<typename T>
concept Hashable = requires(T a)
{
    { std::hash<T>{}(a) } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
};
```

the type of `{ std::hash<T>{}(a) }` is prepended into `std::convertible_to<std::size_t>` to see if it passes the test.

You can add extra constraints within your concept.  Be sure to make sure your constraints non-separable, as it is better to do

```
template<class T>
concept Bob = Alice<T> && Eve<T>;
```

if `Alice` and `Eve` are separable concepts, than to make `Bob` contain all of their requirements.

If you do this separation when possible, the language can know that `Bob` is more-constrained than either `Alice` or `Eve`.  If, on the other hand, you combine all of `Alice` and `Eve`s requirements into one larger `requires` block, the language won't know this.